# Difference between setters, getters and __set__,__get__

Tags: python, setter, getter-setter, getter, magic-methods

Code:

```
class Pizza:
  def __init__(self, toppings):
    self.toppings = toppings
    self._pineapple_allowed = False

  @property
  def pineapple_allowed(self):
    return self._pineapple_allowed

  @pineapple_allowed.setter
  def pineapple_allowed(self, value):
    if value:
      password = input("Enter the password: ")
      if password == "Sw0rdf1sh!":
        self._pineapple_allowed = value
      else:
        raise ValueError("Alert! Intruder!")
```

I'm confused how the `@<func>.setter` decorator differs from just overwriting the `__set__` function in the object.  Same with `@<func>.getter` and `__get__`.

For that matter, I can't think of a use case for `@property` over just setting variables in the class.

Am I thinking about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

With '@property' descriptor you control a single class attribute, in your case `cls.pineapple_allowed`, while `__get__, __set__ and __delete__` are magic methods of descriptor protocol itself. If you overwrite any of the above method in any class, access/assignment/deletion of ANY class attribute will go thru corresponding magic method.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused how the `@<func>.setter` decorator differs from just overwriting the `__set__` function in the object. Same with `@<func>.getter` and `__get__`.

You *can't* overwrite the `__set__` method on the property object directly, and even if you could, it wouldn't do anything, because Python goes directly to the property object's class to find `__set__` when performing attribute assignment. This goes for most double-double-underscore methods when Python is looking for them as the implementation of language features.

Using `.setter` instead records the function in an instance attribute of the property object, which `__set__` will delegate to to perform the setting.